# Sudden disappearing of data in a temporary table

Tags: oracle

I have created a temporary table and I was retrieving data from another table and inserting it to this temporary table. After that I wanted to create another temporary table and insert some data from the previous temporary table.

```
create global temporary table TEMP(
           Col NUMBER);
insert into TEMP select COL from Table1 where COL = 1 commit;
select * from TEMP;
create global temporary table TEMP_2 (Col NUMBER);
select * from TEMP;
```

First off, it shows that the data is inserted in the TEMP table and then after I created a second table and did the second SELECT statement on the TEMP table, it was empty. I don't understand why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a global temporary table is created with the property "on delete commit rows".  When you create another table, Oracle performs an implicit commit and so your data in the first table is deleted.

You can change this by creating the first table as:

```
create global temporary table TEMP(
       Col NUMBER) on commit preserve rows;
```

Or you can reorder your statements:

```
create global temporary table TEMP(
           Col NUMBER);
create global temporary table TEMP_2 (Col NUMBER);

insert into TEMP select COL from Table1 where COL = 1 commit;
select * from TEMP;
select * from TEMP;
```

Remember, in Oracle global temporary tables are permanent objects, they are not something you should normally be creating on-the-fly.